# Show DIVs in custom order

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have some link on my page. When I click on a link, the corresponding DIV should be displayed.
This works as intended:

```
<style>
div{
    display: none;
}
</style>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a").click(function(){
        showDIV(this);
    });
});
function showDIV(param){
    var id = param.id;
    $("#div" + id).show();
}
</script>

<div id="div1">Ro 1</div>
<div id="div2">Ro 2</div>
<div id="div3">Ro 3</div>

<a href="#" id="1">Link 1</a>
<a href="#" id="2">Link 2</a>
<a href="#" id="3">Link 3</a>
```

But I don't want to keep the order of 1,2,3.
So when I click on Link2, then Link3, then Link1, I want the divs to be displayed in the same order, so Div2, Div3, Div1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to display them individualy in another block :

**HTML**

```
<div class="reiter reiter_oben" id="div1">Ro 1</div>
<div class="reiter reiter_oben" id="div2">Ro 2</div>
<div class="reiter reiter_oben" id="div3">Ro 3</div>

<span id="display"></span>

<a href="#" id="1">Link 1</a>
<a href="#" id="2">Link 2</a>
<a href="#" id="3">Link 3</a>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a").click(function(){
        showDIV(this);
    });
});
function showDIV(param){
    var id = param.id;
    $('#display').append($("#div" + id).show());
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/t53LtL9q/

Answer (score 0):

You could use `flexbox` with `order`

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a").click(function(){
        showDIV(this);
    });
});

var order = 1;

function showDIV(param){
    var id = param.id;
    var $el = $("#div" + id);
    $el.css("order",order);
    $el.show();
    order ++;
}
```

```css
.parent{
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
}


.reiter{
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="reiter reiter_oben" id="div1">Ro 1</div>
  <div class="reiter reiter_oben" id="div2">Ro 2</div>
  <div class="reiter reiter_oben" id="div3">Ro 3</div>
</div>

<a href="#" id="1">Link 1</a>
<a href="#" id="2">Link 2</a>
<a href="#" id="3">Link 3</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a").click(function(){
        showDIV($(this).attr('id'));
    });
});
function showDIV(param){
    
    $("#div"+param).css("display","block");
}
```

```css
div{
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="reiter reiter_oben" id="div1">Ro 1</div>
<div class="reiter reiter_oben" id="div2">Ro 2</div>
<div class="reiter reiter_oben" id="div3">Ro 3</div>

<a href="#" id="1">Link 1</a>
<a href="#" id="2">Link 2</a>
<a href="#" id="3">Link 3</a>
```

Comment: if you think that it is helpfull then you can vote up my ans @user1170330

Comment: No, it is the same what I had. It displays the DIVs always in the same order: 1,2,3. But I want them to be displayed in the order I clicked them, so e.g. 3,1,2.

Answer (score 0):

small changes to your code, add a container to move the divs around in

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var contain = document.getElementById('container');
    function showDIV(param){
        var id = "div" + param.id;
        var div = document.getElementById(id);
        contain.appendChild(div);
        $(div).show();
    }
    
    $("a").click(function(){
        showDIV(this);
    });
});
```

```css
div.reiter{
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
    <div class="reiter reiter_oben" id="div1">Ro 1</div>
    <div class="reiter reiter_oben" id="div2">Ro 2</div>
    <div class="reiter reiter_oben" id="div3">Ro 3</div>
</div>
<a href="#" id="1">Link 1</a>
<a href="#" id="2">Link 2</a>
<a href="#" id="3">Link 3</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to have the divs in another container and then append them to another container where you they will visible:

```js
$("a").click(function() {
  var id = this.id;
  $('.visible-container').append($("#div" + id));
});
```

```css
.hidden-container > div {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="hidden-container">
  <div id="div1">1</div>
  <div id="div2">2</div>
  <div id="div3">3</div>
</div>
<div class="visible-container"></div>

<a href="#" id="1">Link 1</a>
<a href="#" id="2">Link 2</a>
<a href="#" id="3">Link 3</a>
```